# Does anyone know what language this is?

Tags: historical-linguistics

Maybe even what the English translation is? I believe that there are hedera's present, directing it towards Latin maybe? Sorry for the bad quality [image]

Comment: @jknappen Thank you! I believe you are right from the examples I just saw of what you mentioned :) Now I'll try the fun part of trying to decipher it :D

Comment: Think of it as medieval txtng, with emoticons. We didn't just invent this lately, you know.

Answer (score 2):

It is Latin written in a hand I can hardly read and full of medieval abbreviatures that are hard to decipher (for instance, the word looking like Dõs reads "Dominus"). If you really want to read it, get a book teaching medieval abbreviatures.

Comment: If this is Latin why can't anyone read it?

Comment: Can you read it?